# How to get the PID for a background process in C code

Tags: c

I am executing a linux command using the system call in my C program. code snippet -

```
cmd = "sudo conntrack -E -p udp -e NEW | logger -t log-conntrack -p daemon.notice &";

system(cmd);
```

This command starts 3 processes, now I somehow want the process id of the "conntrack" process (PID - 31951  in below example).

```
root     31949  0.0  0.4   2356  1060 pts/2    S    17:39   0:00 sudo conntrack -E -p udp -e NEW -o id
root     31950  0.0  0.1   1716   504 pts/2    S    17:39   0:00 logger -t log-conntrack -p daemon.notice
root     31951  0.0  0.2   1852   544 pts/2    S    17:39   0:00 conntrack -E -p udp -e NEW -o id
```

please help.
thanks

Comment: `system` doesn't background the process, it waits until the command returns, are you running it in a separate thread or after a `fork()`?

Comment: the cmd mentioned above has "&" at the end which runs it in background.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to obtain the PID of the child of the `sudo` process (the `conntrack` process) run by the shell that is run by the system command for you.

You'd have to go groping around the output of `ps` or its equivalent.

If you `fork()` a child process, the parent process is told explicitly about the PID of the child.  However, there is no easy way to find the PID of the child process started by `system()`.  Nor is there any standard way for a process to learn about its grandchildren.  In your case, you have a shell run by `system()`, which in turn runs `logger` in one child and `sudo` in a second before it exits; and the `sudo` in turn runs `conntrack` (and, it seems, `sudo` waits for `conntrack` to complete, rather than simply replacing itself with `conntrack`).

Comment: yes, I thought so. Is there any other way to execute the above command in C and obtain the pid of the bkgnd process?

Comment: You could do what the shell does to run `logger` and `sudo` without much difficulty - so you could track either or both of those processes (without the intermediate shell imposed on you by `system()`).  However, you are still stuck with `sudo` launching its own child, `conntrack`, and I don't know of a simple way to get the child PID - unless there are lesser-known options to `sudo` to do the job (I can't see anything promising in sudo v.1.7.4).

Comment: instead of using the system(), i can do what the system would do, i.e. fork() a process and let the child exec() the command and then wait on pids of the children?

Comment: Yes - though you won't be able to wait directly on the `conntrack` process, but you can wait for the `sudo` process to complete after the `conntrack` process completes.  `sudo` will relay the exit status of `conntrack` back to your program, though - within limits.  The main limit is that if your program dies from a signal (and perhaps produces a core dump), then `sudo` cannot relay that information perfectly; however, it can (and will) tell that the command failed.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information, also since there is a pipe between the 2 commands, i would need to create pipe as well.I found a post by you which is as follows -

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189475/passing-a-pipe-as-a-parameter-in-exec/5189548#5189548

Answer (score 0):

```
char cmd[] = "(sudo sh -c 'conntrack -E -p udp -e NEW& echo $! >&2' |"
             " logger -t log-conntrack -p daemon.notice&) 2>&1";
int pid = 0;    // let's assume pid_t fits in an int
FILE *stream = popen(cmd, "r");
if (stream) fscanf(stream, "%d", &pid), pclose(stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Program to print its Process ID, Parent Process ID and Group ID

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() 
{
        pid_t pid, ppid;
    gid_t gid;

    /* get the process id */
    if ((pid = getpid()) < 0) {
      perror("
unable to get pid");
    } else {
      printf("
The process id is %d", pid);
    }

    /* get the parent process id */
    if ((ppid = getppid()) < 0) {
      perror("
unable to get the ppid");
    } else {
      printf("
The parent process id is %d", ppid);
    }

    /* get the group process id */
    if ((gid = getgid()) < 0) {
      perror("
unable to get the group id
");
    } else {
      printf("
The group id is %d
", gid);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: getpid() and getppid() doesnt work for background processes. thanks anyways.